# Will Allah forgive me for wishing someone's death?

Tags: allah, forgiveness

There are a lots of people dying because of corona. I don't know what happened to me recently I just said people should die of corona.I regret saying those things. I said that in mind. I don't wish anyone's death or harm. Will Allah forgive me for that. Will Allah accept my apology or punish me with death?

Answer (score 2):

Allah knows what is best and what your real intention is. Plus, not all bad prayers uttered by man, will be granted by Him. The commentators, among them Ibn Abbas radhiyallahu ‘anhuma and others said :

> *"That this is a bad prayer of a person for himself, or his son, when*
> *he is angry, which in fact he himself does not like when the prayer is*
> *granted. If God answers the prayer of ugliness, many of them will*
> *perish. But by His grace, He did not answer this prayer." **-Sahih al-Bukhari 1496 & Muslim 130***

However, it's best that we always seek for forgiveness from Allah and avoid this kind of thinking.

Wallahualam.